# pgbouncer login rejected

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

The second day I can not overcome the connection error through pgbouncer if I use `auth_type = hba`:

```
postgres=# create user monitoring with password 'monitoring';
postgres=# create database monitoring owner monitoring;
postgres=# \du+ monitoring
                   List of roles
 Role name  | Attributes | Member of | Description
------------+------------+-----------+-------------
 monitoring |            | {}        |


postgres=# \l+ monitoring
                                                    List of databases
    Name    |   Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges |  Size   | Tablespace | Description
------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+---------+------------+-------------
 monitoring | monitoring | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                   | 7861 kB | pg_default |
```

`/var/lib/pgsql/10/data/pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

host    monitoring      monitoring      0.0.0.0/0               trust
local   monitoring      monitoring                              trust
```

`/etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini`:

```
pidfile                 = /var/run/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid
reserve_pool_size       = 5
reserve_pool_timeout    = 2
listen_port             = 6432
listen_addr             = *
auth_type               = hba
auth_hba_file           = /etc/pgbouncer/hba_bouncer.conf
auth_file               = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
logfile                 = /var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log
log_connections         = 0
log_disconnections      = 0
log_pooler_errors       = 1
max_client_conn         = 5000
server_idle_timeout     = 30
pool_mode               = transaction
server_reset_query      =
admin_users             = root
stats_users             = root,monitoring

[databases]
*                       = client_encoding=UTF8 host=localhost port=5432 pool_size=1000
```

In `pg_hba.conf` of pgbouncer I also tried to specify specific addresses of interfaces of the server with mask /32, also mask /8, /16 (real mask of my network segment).

The result is only one: login rejected!

`/etc/pgbouncer/hba_bouncer.conf`:

```
host    monitoring            monitoring            0.0.0.0/0               trust
host    monitoring            monitoring            127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

`/etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt`:

```
"monitoring" "monitoring"
```

Connection attempt:

```
# psql -U monitoring -p 5432 -h 127.0.0.1
psql (10.1)
Type "help" for help.

monitoring=>


# psql -U monitoring -p 6432 -h 127.0.0.1
psql: ERROR:  login rejected
```

Comment: What is in `/var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log`?

Comment: `2019-08-09 14:01:32.077 23240 WARNING C-0x7873e0: monitoring/monitoring@127.0.0.1:36395 pooler error: login rejected`

Comment: Good. Then look in the PostgreSQL server log for the reason.

Comment: There's nothing to see. It is empty at this problem because to PostgreSQL session does not up. Pgbouncer kills session with me by answering: login rejected

Comment: I'd attach a debugger to pgBouncer to see what its problem is. As a first measure, look into the source where that error message is thrown. Perhaps that can give you a clue.

Answer (score 1):

We have a use case similar to yours. We are running version 1.12.0 and we ran into the same issue where we also got the "ERROR: login rejected" message.

Turned out after investigation that the permissions on our pg_hba.conf for pg_bouncer was incorrect. Once we gave pgbouncer read permissions, it was working as expected. Unfortunately nothing in the higher logging that we turned on revealed this, and we happened to stumbled across this solution through testing on our own.

Ps. the password hash in the pgbouncer config we had left as "" as we're using trust on our connection. I don't think there is anything different in our config to what you posted otherwise.

Comment: I have also encountered this problem. Also check the permissions on `userlist.txt`; I had created that file as root and forgotten to assign pgbouncer read permissions.